# Lifo Typeahead on new dom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a Symfony2 app, and have a form with repeated form elements, where I am using Lifo's Typeahead extension. 
https://github.com/lifo101/typeahead-bundle

It works great on form elements that exist on load, but when I add new form elements using JQuery, the the Typeahead isn't working. I'm not very good with Javascript, so I'm struggling to understand how to make the script work with the new fields. Does anyone have any suggestions? I think I need to re-initialise the script but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for trying the bundle.

The problem is I never considered dynamic insertion of DOM elements for my typeahead widget so the current version isn't going to work with inputs that are dynamically inserted into the DOM.

However, I've now updated my code to properly trigger for any existing or newly inserted elements into the DOM. As long as the inserted HTML is in the proper format that my typeahead bundle expects it should just automatically work as soon as you insert your HTML.